# use facebook buil-in like action with custom object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Im developing an application for my website with user generated content.
I've succesfully posted custom actions+custom objects but now I'm trying to use the builtin like action with a custom object so it shows

"user likes a "custom object" on appname" on their timeline

this is the header i've also included og:url, og:image, description, and so on

```
      <meta property="og:type" content="appname:custom_object" />
```

my code so far (same I used to post custom actions+custom object succesfully)

```
   if(user_clicks_on_action_button){
    try{
        $params = array('custom_object_name'=> 'url_to_object');
        $statusUpdate = $facebook->api("/me/og.likes", 'post', $params);
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
        echo $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

but this is the message I get:

```
         The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: object.
```

according to facebook documentation is possible:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/
but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You have to use the index 'object' in your parameter array.

Comment: I've JUST realized that. I didn't know there was no need to specify the custom object type in the array when posting, since it is retrieved from the meta tags of the url.
Even though I realized my mistake on my own. Your answer is correct. Thank you.

Comment: @CBroe can I trigger likes like these from PHP sdk without using the tags in the <head> area? By specifying object title, image, etc in the request array ? I keep getting `conflicting og:type found in path (object) and 'properties'` if I try that.